# How do I resolve ambiguity between my project DLL and a DLL in the GAC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, dll, gac

I am currently working on [**another issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322366/how-do-i-serve-up-an-unauthorized-page-when-a-user-is-not-in-the-authorized-roles) in my ASP.NET MVC project.  In an effort to better understand what is happening in the codebase I decided to reference the ASP.NET MVC Source Code project in my own project by adding the solution file to my references.

When I did this, I started getting HTTP 404 errors.

It just so happens I had a breakpoint set on the `OnException()` method of the `HandleErrorAttribute`, otherwise it might have taken a long time to find the actual problem.  When I hover over the `filterContext` parameter in the `OnException` method call, I get this `Exception` description:

```
    The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous: 
        it could come from assembly [path to assembly in GAC] 
        or from assembly [path to assembly in my project]
```

The assembly in the GAC is there because I installed the [**ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC2 release**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7aba081a-19b9-44c4-a247-3882c8f749e3&displaylang=en).

How do I best resolve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Web.Mvc` is referenced in `Web.Config`, in the `<Compilation><Assemblies>` section.  In my application, this entry has a public key token attribute.

I solved the problem by removing the `PublicKeyToken` attribute.

So this:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

becomes this:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
```

Apparently Visual Studio can't find the signed assembly in the GAC when the `PublicKeyToken` is missing, so it is forced to use the local project assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but maybe your answer lies in the assemblyBinding tag of your config:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx

Comment: System.Web.Mvc is not referenced in AssemblyBinding, but it *is* referenced in Compilation/Assemblies. I think I solved it. Thanks for the assist. +1